# Using array class type parameters in PHP

Tags: php, function, object, parameters

Given I have the following method:

```
public function create(array $notificationTypes, NotificationSettings $notificationSettings)
{

}
```

Is it in any way possible to make sure the `$notificationTypes` parameter is an array of `NotificationType`? I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
 public function create(array NotificationType $notificationTypes, NotificationSettings $notificationSettings)
 {

 }

 public function create(NotificationType[] $notificationTypes, NotificationSettings $notificationSettings)
 {

 }
```

If this isn't possible, is there no other way than looping through `$notificationTypes` and check if each element is an instance of `NotificationType`?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php ?

Comment: No, you only can check if passed argument is array and inside a function check every element of this array.

Comment: You have to manually iterate over all the elements of your array, PHP does not support that kind of type-hinting.

Comment: Alright, if you can answer the question, I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Try if this link helps you http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: The language does not support it natively. You can emulate it with regular objects (I've seen a few typed collection implementations out there) but it needs some extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, you cannot do that in the method declaration. In a reasonably recent PHP version you can check the array items' types like this in the function body:

```
if (count(array_filter($notificationTypes,
              function($inst) {
                  return ! ($inst instanceof NotificationType));
              }))) {
    throw new Exception('Only instances of NotificationType please!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to check types manually you can use [expectsAll](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#expectsallconstraints-array-args-array-atpositions---otherwisethrow--invalidargumentexception) function from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl). There are also other functions and predefined constraints for argument validation.

```
use function \nspl\args\expectsAll;

//...

public function create(array $notificationTypes, NotificationSettings $notificationSettings)
{
    expectsAll(NotificationType::class, $notificationTypes);
}

// ...
```